# iPhone 5 Updates Frozen

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 5. I have apps that are updating but never finish.
I tried restarting. I tried some examples on this website. I waited days for it to refresh. Nothing seems to work. The "Updates All" is greyed out. You can't select it. Recently upgraded to iOS9 9.0.1(13A404).

Answer (score 1):

I would connect your phone to a computer, open iTunes and delete the apps from there that are not updating properly. Once this is done, simply unplug your phone from your computer and re-download those applications.

Answer (score 0):

If the previous answer doesn't work re: deleting the hung apps, your next best bet would be to do a factory restore and reload from backup - it almost sounds like the upgrade partially failed.

Instructions for doing this [can be found on Apple's site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252)